# Jquery - Squares fade and come back

Tags: jquery

I have a bit of a problem with some squares of mine.  They are supposed to fade when the user mouses over and then come back to the normal opacity when they mouse out.  The problem is that they do not go back to the normal opacity when I mouse out.  How do I fix this?

```
<div class="test"></div>

$('.test').each(function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '1.0'}, 500);
    $(this).hover(function(){    
        $(this).stop(1).animate({'opacity': '1.0'}, 500);    
    }, function(){    
        $(this).stop(1).animate({'opacity': '0.6'}, 500)     // at the end of animation
    });
});
```

I have made a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ebawad/2)

Any help / tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In all the browsers I tried, including chrome, it stays at an opacity of 0.6 instead of returning to 1.0.

Comment: The two answers as of now are good, but what I am looking to do is have the hovered object have an opacity of 1.0 and the other be 0.6 to that all the emphasis is on the hovered one.  I want to do what you guys have said in reverse, but have all return to 1.0 when the mouse leaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/wKApE/

```
$('.test').mouseenter(function(event){
  $(event.target).addClass('active');  
  $('.test').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
    {
      $(this).stop(1).animate({'opacity': '0.6'}, 500); 
    }
  });
});
$('.test').mouseleave(function(event){
  $(event.target).removeClass('active');
  $('.test').each(function(){
  $(this).stop(1).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 500);
  });
});​
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do.  I'm not always the best at explaining what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You simply mixed up the order of the fades.

```
$(this).hover(function(){    
    $(this).stop(1).animate({'opacity': '0.6'}, 500)     // hover over        
}, function(){    
    $(this).stop(1).animate({'opacity': '1.0'}, 500);    // hover out
});
```

Check out the function signature from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
hover( handlerIn(eventObject) , handlerOut(eventObject)  )
```

The first function is for when the mouse enters the element and the second is for when the mouse leaves the element.

Comment: This works except that I wanted the mouse over object to have an opacity of 1 instead of 0.6.  Will still +1.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler solution

```
$('.test').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(500, 0.6);
});​
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5R8Y9/

Comment: This works except that I wanted the mouse over object to have an opacity of 1 instead of 0.6.  Will still +1.

Comment: No problem, I'm not always the best at explaining things clearly.